# How can we use custom methods in where clause?

Tags: laravel

I want to use `getNewsLetterWorkshop()` instead of `where('code1','=','NSL')` in `isUserBelongsToWorkshop($role)` method.

This is my service class and method

```
/**
 * @throws CustomAuthorizationException
 */
public function getNewsLetterWorkshop()
{
    $workshop = Workshop::where('code1', '=', 'NSL')->first();
    if (!$workshop) {
        throw new CustomAuthorizationException('Unauthorized');
    }
}
```

This is authorization class

```
/**
 * @param $role
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isUserBelongsToWorkshop($role)
{
    $workshops = $this->newsLetter = AuthorizationsService::getInstance()->getWorkshop();
    if ('M1' == Auth::user()->role || 'M0' == Auth::user()->role) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $workshop = Workshop::with([
            'meta' => function ($q) use ($role) {
                $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                $q->whereIn('role', $role);
            },
        ])->where('code1', '=', 'NSL')->first();
        if ($workshop) {
            $workshopDetails = $workshop->meta->count();
            if ($workshopDetails) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a function within a `where` clause, it would need to return a query, e.g.

```
function foo($query) {
    return $query->where(...);
}

function bar() {
    $data = Model::where(function ($query) {
        return $this->foo($query);
    })->get()
}
```

Although, I would suggest keeping the `where` as is, and doing the `if (!$workshop) {...` after that. I do not think you would be able to perform this check and throw an error inside the function included in the `where` clause, because that function should take in a query builder instance, and return one too, therefore you would have no way of checking the result of the query.

Comment: everything is working but if doesn't find any workshop. It is throwing exception error rather it should throw custom exception error

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function Modules\\Newsletter\\Exceptions\\CustomAuthorizationException::render(), 1 passed in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\work\\ops\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php on line 169 and exactly 2 expected",

Comment: Hi @anuragsingh, could you update your post with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Looking into Laravel's Query Scope features

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes

On your `Workshop` model, you could add a scope for `newsLetterWorkshops` like so:

---

**Workshop::class**

```
    /**
     * Scope a query to only news letter workshops.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeNewsLetterWorkshops($query)
    {
        return $query->where('code1','=','NSL');
    }
```

---

You could then use this like so:

```
Workshop::newsLetterWorkshops()->first();
```

Comment: What is it returning? I can't help without feedback ;)